# emoji codes vs unicode codepoints in Git commit

Tags: git, github, unicode, gitmoji

I'm seing emojis invading the git area and I recently stumbled upon [Gitmoji](https://gitmoji.carloscuesta.me/). This is all nice and cool because emojis convey immediate meaning.

But I can't understand why almost all of these emojis rely on emoji codes like `:fire:` instead of using their unicode codepoint `U+1F525` ().

When using git on the command line, it's very annoying to see the shortcodes… Can someone enlighten me?

UPDATE

Eventhough the @Makoto's answer makes sense. I'm better off using *real* emojis in my commits. So I rolled out [a git hook](https://github.com/Buzut/git-emojis-hook) to dynamically replace markdown emojis to unicode.

Comment: I've also discovered [emojify](https://github.com/mrowa44/emojify) to render emojis in the terminal.

Comment: [VSCode extension that have option to use either unicode or markdown emoji and makes commit for you](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjaminadk.emojis4git)

Comment: @Buzut This issue can be useful for this topic https://github.com/carloscuesta/gitmoji/issues/527

Comment: @johannchopin Indeed! I added a comment on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a symptom of GitHub-flavored Markdown.  [There's a *lot* of emoji](https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/) which is covered by this and instead of enforcing code points (which they can't guarantee convey *any* meaning), they use `:fire:` which, even if you can't render the emoji, conveys meaning.

Comment: So in your opinion, what should be done? Keep up using these? Because I was thinking of writing a git hook to automatically convert the emojis text codes (let's admit it, it's more user friendly to type) to the actual unicode charpoint for a set of usefull ones for a given repo.

Comment: You can do what you like; this is more for your edification and convenience than mine.  Just be aware that a Unicode point means next to nothing to humans.

Comment: Sure, but unless emojis are from one of the last unicode releases, it's supported pretty much everywhere I guess. So humans usually won't see them.

Comment: You can try [emojiPy](https://github.com/m9810223/emojiPy).